# dcc.store for live-dating data table DASH

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I implemented a live-update feature to the add column function based on the documentation on editable DataTable https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/editable such that a new column is added to the datatable when the CSV file is updated. I've got the callback working and I need to save the state of the datatable in a dcc.store, which was kindly recommended to me, so that I store the current number of columns, and add only the newly updated columns based on the new CSV data. I need to do this because users input data the table, and if I live update the whole table the data is lost. I do not know if I can access the user input data in dcc.store, so instead I only wish to add on new columns to the datatable thereby preserving using input.

My question: is there a way I can assess the current number of columns in an existing data
table?

```
app.layout = html.Div([
            dcc.Store(id='mystore'),
            html.Div([dash_table.DataTable(
                id='editing-columns',
                columns=[{
                    'name': 'Parameter',
                    'id': 'column1',
                    'deletable': True,
                    'renamable': True
        }],
              
    },
                data=[
                    {'column1': j}
                    for j in table_contents
        ],
               
    ]),
])



@app.callback(Output('mystore', 'data'),
              Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals'),
              State('editing-columns', 'data'))
def serve_layout(n,data):
   print(data) 
   data2 = json.dumps(data)
    

    return data2
```

Output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way I can assess the current number of columns in an existing data table?

Yes, you can read in the table's `data` prop as `State`. That will give you everything in the table, and you can easily pull the column count from there.